# How to check for a specific colour on screen on Mac (python)

Tags: python, macos, pynput

I am trying to make a bot for Piano Tiles online on mac. I have the code for pressing the relevant keys. I now am trying to check whether there is a grey tile that I need to press. Here is my code so far. (Python)

> import time 
>   import pynput from pynput.keyboard 
>   import Key, Controller keyboard = Controller()
>
> leftKey = True
>
> if leftKey == True:   keyboard.press('a')     keyboard.release('a')
>
> centerLeft = True
>
> if centerLeft == True:    keyboard.press('s')     keyboard.release('s')
>
> centerRight = True
>
> if centerRight == True:   keyboard.press('d')     keyboard.release('d')
>
> rightKey = True
>
> if rightKey == True:  keyboard.press('f')     keyboard.release('f')

If anyone can let me know how to check if there is a key that I need to press and then press it that would be great. Thanks. I have looked everywhere online for an answer but its only for Windows.

Comment: You have formatted your code as a quote. Please click `edit` underneath your question, remove that formatting, select your code with the mouse and re-format with `{}` button instead - beside **Bold** and *Italic*. Thanks.

Comment: Please add image so we know what we are looking for/at.